# Private Chat Messaging django Such as facebook

Tags: python, django, chat, django-channels

I want to implement a private chat messaging app just like on linkedin or facebook as they have a chat bar on the bottom bar of the screen. I have created the chat application as a different app on the project as the user has to go the messages/ url in order to chat with the user, but in order to make chat boxes like that on facebook home page, do I have to make chat as a separate app or just make the chat app within my main app. I don't have any strategy to it. any help towards the approach would help alot.

Comment: My understanding is to make it within the same app, simply a collapsable and extendable popup box for the chat. Btw, This question doesn't really fit the guidelines of S/O. Consider asking it on other exchange sites, or even Reddit for that matter.

Comment: Thank you, I will be trying this now and can you please guide which exchange to ask on? as there are many on inernet

Comment: Go with reddit, or quora.